# PHP Select Certain Part of Text File

Tags: php, file

I have a text file that going to use as a config file and its a .txt

Text File

```
#Config

<licence>
Licence Key
</Licence>

<Name>
Company Name
</Name>
```

So I need the PHP to only read the contents within the tags, I dont know if this is possible, i have managed to use a script below that returns the whole file.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("config.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("config.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: You can't only "read the contents within the tags". Nobody knows where the tag is until you read the whole file so that you can search all the occurrences of the tags.

Comment: Read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Or make it a full XML file and use an XML Document reader

Comment: I agree with @RiggsFolly, make it a valid XML file and just parse it with an XML Document Reader. See [SimpleXML](/http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Comment: Writing an xml file and calling it a txt file will only lead to confusion and pain.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using regular expressions.

For example:

```
preg_match_all('%<([A-Za-z]+)>([.\n]+)</\1>%', $text);
```

See the PHP documentation for more examples:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-all-examples
(Example #2 has a similar situation as yours)

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already a regex solution but I really think you should just use a `.json` file or even better a separate php file where you could place the settings. If you're already working in PHP, I don't see why you would need to complicate things by parsing a custom plaintext file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your text file to an XML file, since you already have XML tags in the text file. Simply add the XML header line at the top of the file and then save it as .xml.

Use simplexml_file_load() to create a SimpleXML object and use the tags as the properties.

```
$xml = simplexml_file_load('config.xml');

$licence = $xml->Licence;
$company_name = $xml->Name
```